# How to know if laptop/windows is used and restored (factory reset)?

Tags: windows, reset, restore

I've bought a Toshiba SATELLITE E45W-C4200X on May 27, 2016 and when I start it it looks like a first run "Settings up things for you and choose your language and country ...".

My first question : windows factory reset will  get windows back to this point ?

I've check the warranty on Toshiba website it shows that it started the day I've first setup my windows.

[image: Toshiba warranty]

Second question : Do a windows factory reset also reset the warranty ?

Third question : is there a way to know if my laptop is used before and restored ?

Thank you :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers will follow in list format.

1. Factory Reset doesnt really mean much in computer terms. If you mean a clean install of Windows, then it doesnt matter when you do it, because the computer will always poll Microsoft servers for the correct time when they start up anyway.

If you have a way to actually restore the OS to exactly as it looked when you bought the laptop, I actually would personally recommend against it and advise that you just do a clean installation of Windows, as laptop manufacturers tend to load down the operating system with lots of junk and bloatware.

2. I cant imagine a world where changing the operating system would void the warranty of the hardware, but then again I wouldn't completely put it past modern computer manufacturers either.

I'd say there's a 99% chance you're fine to refresh/reinstall the operating system of your choice, as the Toshiba website clearly already recognizes your device as genuine and registered.

3. I dont really think there's any easy way to tell if a computer has been used before if the operating system has been reinstalled.

You may be able to check the BOIS for signs of changes but beyond that I doubt there's anything software related that you could do.

Comment: I don't want to refresh/reinstall the operating system, I just want to make sure the laptop/windows is not used before ...

Comment: I really dont understand the question to be honest. Are you worried that someone sold you a used product as new?

Comment: YES that what I am worried about ! thank you... 
is there a way to know ?

Comment: I honestly cant think of any off the top of my head that wouldnt require ridiculous amounts of specialized equipment. Which isnt to say its impossible to tell, but I just cant think of one. Its actually a problem I've never considered. I suppose I'd look for the little details. Check the surface of the device for scratches and dirt, and make sure it has the correct amount/speed of RAM as well as the advertised HardDrive space.

Comment: WAIT, I THOUGHT OF IT. Download a S.M.A.R.T reader and check how many hours the harddrive has been on, if it seems like longer than you've owned the laptop, than its used!

Comment: You're a genius :D Thank you ... I will absolutely try it !!

Comment: No problem man. Good luck!